# Error in webpack during build but not dev: "ERROR in static[...] from UglifyJS. Unexpected token: punc (...)"

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Came across this error after adding a module (in my case it's `vue2-dropzone` but apparently this occurs with some other node modules as well) to my codebase. It occurred when I ran `npm run build`, but everything worked fine using the webpack dev server (`npm run dev`).

```
ERROR in static/js/vendor.5efd79c0d4a823d6add3.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: punc (() [./node_modules/vue2-dropzone/dist/vue2Dropzone.js:1,41920][static/js/vendor.5efd79c0d4a823d6add3.js:42174,41885]
```

Found a simple solution to the problem, which I'm posting as an answer below -- but would very much like to hear if anyone knows WHY this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that for reasons above my pay grade, `babel-loader` must be used to load this particular module. Or something like that. The solution is to modify your `webpack.base.conf.js` file to include the offending module (whichever one appears in the error above) in the babel-loader rule as follows:

```
{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/<NAME_OF_NODE_MODULE>')]
}
```

**UPDATE** (per [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) in the comments): This happens when UglifyJS requires Babel's features (e.g. language extensions) in order to understand a given module's code.

Comment: It means that you have JS code that Uglify cannot understand without Babel (eg, language extensions or newer features).